# Haskell filter function on strings

Tags: haskell, types, filter

Is there a way to use the filter function on Strings, this way:

```
filter (=="!") "!!some!!_!!string!!"
```

should output `"some_string"` (case above). Right now all i get is a type error:

```
Couldn't match expected type `[Char]' against inferred type `Char'
```

If i change the second filter argument type to ["!!some!!_!!string!!"], the type error disappears, yet only an empty list is outputted. (Not exactly what i want)

I thought that strings were lists but obviously "!!some!!_!!string!!" isn't regarded as a list but as a char.

Any hints someone ?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
Prelude> filter (/='!') "!!some!!_!!string!!"
"some_string"
```

The type of `filter` is `(a -> Bool) -> [a] -> [a]`. Since the 2nd argument is a String = [Char], meaning `[a]` = String = [Char], we infer that `a` must be a Char. The function therefore must take a Char as input. Therefore, you need to use `'!'`, not `"!"`.

Comment: +1 Say what you will about Hindley-Milner-ish type systems, but they do make type signatures more useful.

Comment: i'm not saying anything, i just want my code to work easily. And strong typing combined to functional programming has its pitfalls.

Comment: @kiltek Pitfalls like having to say what you mean?  This isn't a nit-picky error.  You were asking it to remove all elements of a list that matched something that couldn't possibly be an element of the list.  That's a bug.  The type system caught it at compile time.  That seems like a pretty good deal to me.